# NativeScript TabView icon positioning

Tags: android, ios, swift, nativescript

NativeScript doesn't seem to support font icons only in the tab bar, but I got very close based on numerous examples. But I can't get this function working to center the icons vertically on ios as [detailed here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4831). They are 8px too high in the tab bar.

One solution presented on the previously linked page is the following:

View:

```
<TabView (loaded)="onTabViewLoaded($event)">
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '\uf2bd'}" >
    <Tab1></Tab1>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '\uf03e'}">
    <Tab2></Tab2>
  </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Component:

```
onTabViewLoaded: ({ object: tabView }) => {
   tabView.eachChild((child) => {
    child._iosViewController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = {
        horizontal: 0,
        vertical: -8
    };
  });
}
```

But this throws an error in nativescript 4.0.0:

```
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child._iosViewController.tabBarItem')
```

Is there an error in the code? Another way to center these icons vertically?